# Firebase can't retrieve data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Model Class:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Points {

public String score;

public Points(){

}

public Points(String score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public String getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(String score) {
    this.score = score;
    }
}
```

Code for updating:

```
  private void updateUser(String name) {
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (!name.equals("")) {
        dbRefer.child("User").child(user.getUid()).child("score").setValue(name);
        Toast.makeText(this, "update Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Code for retrieving:

```
 private void addUserChangeListener() {
    final FirebaseUser getData = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    // User data change listener
    dbRefer.child("User").child(getData.getUid()).child("score").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Points user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Points.class);

            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Retrieved Data is: " + getData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Check for null
            if (user == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "User data is null!");
                return;
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "User data is changed!" + user.getScore());

            // Display newly updated name and email
            mTvShowData.setText(user.getScore());

            // clear edit text
            mTxtEdtData.setText("");

            toggleButton();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Can't Get data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }
```

Code for updating is working, what I am facing now is the retrieving part, I can't seem to get the data out from my database. Help and guidance is needed thanks.

Comment: did you check the permissions i.e. DataBase rule in your firebase console?

Comment: Can you post your points.class file as well as your database structure?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've added my Points class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I'd pull information just as you are, as objects, but because your only pulling one piece of information, instead of creating a points object and all of that I would just pull it manually and put it.

```
     dbRefer.child("User").child(getData.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("score").getValue();
mTvShowData.setText(name);
```

Comment: If your just pulling two and placing them in TextViews or something I'd just pull them each manually, else if I'm using the info to populate lists or something I'd pull the information as objects.

Comment: so for recommendation pulling it to textviews are better doing it manually, else use the info as object if populating it as a list?

Comment: Yeah pretty much. Anytime I want just pieces of the data I just pull them manually, like for maybe putting in a profile picture or a rating bar and any situation where I'm just looking for a piece. If I'm populating an array or there's a case I need a few pieces of the information and that information needs to be kept separate then I'll usually make them into classes to pull the data all together.   If that answered your question by the way will you mark it as answered?

Comment: alright done, thanks Robert for the tips and advice, much appreciated

Comment: No problem. Using Firebase is really confusing at first but don't worry once you figure out the nuances it's really easy.